# Finding a substring in a column of CSV file

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, csv

I have a csv file with around 15000 lines and multiple columns. The data set looks like this:

```
A,B,C,   message               D, E, F
a,b,c,Hi how are you ?          d,e,f
a,b,c,Hi Hello.Are you ok?     d,e,f
a,b,This >are< should not be counted,d,e,f
a,b,c,Hi I'm good. Are you ok ? d,e,f
a,b,c,Hi You are good, are you? d,e,f
a,b,c,I dare to add this line   d,e,f
```

Here, how can I have to count the occurrences of the word 'are' in the message column using UNIX shell commands?

Comment: 1) Could there be `are` in other columns which should not be counted? (Otherwise it's trivial!) 2) Should `Are` with capital `A` be counted, too? 3) Is there a comma missing after the `C` in the first line?

Comment: 1)Yes, there could be 'are' in different columns which should not be counted.      2) 'Are'  is case - insensitive. 3) No, I think I didn't added it. Those are column headers. @philippos

Comment: I added some special cases to example: `are` in wrong column, two `are` in one line and `are` being part of `dare`. Is it right you want 1 `are` in lines 2, 3, 5 and 7, 2 `are` in line 6 and none in line 4?

Comment: 1. this is not valid CSV.  Fields containing the field separator should be enclosed in double-quotes.  2. the line with `You are good, are you?` contains a comma, which is the field separator.  That line has 7 fields rather than the usual 6.   3. it looks like there's a missing `,` before column `D`.  if that's the case then the `You are good` line has 8 fields rather than the normal 7.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
 grep -oc are file
```

- `-o` Print only the matched part.
- `-c` print the count of matching line.

You can add `-i` option if u need the result for `Are` also. Which will ignore the case sensitive of matching pattern

If we have multiple matching patterns in same line...

```
grep -o are file | wc -l
```

Using AWK:

```
awk -F ',' '$4 ~ /are/ {count++} END{print count}' file
awk -F ',' '$4 ~ /[Aa]re/ {count++} END{print count}' file
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works @msp9011. How to copy the rows containing the word 'are' and store them in a text file?

Comment: @KrishnaManchodu `grep are file > fileOut.txt`

Comment: Thanks @msp9011. It's really working.

Comment: I found a strange thing @msp9011. It collects all the rows that are having 'are' in any one column. But I need to collect those rows which have 'are' in their fourth column i.e. even if it is present in third column and not in fourth column it should not consider that row. Also for the rows that contain 'are' in their fourth row should have the numerical values in fifth column above a threshold value, say 10. All the rows that satisfy these conditions should be written in the text file. Regards.

Comment: 1) You should probably mention the `-o` is a GNU `grep` extension. 2) The `grep` solutions count matches in the wrong column. 3) The `awk` solution doesn't count multiple occurences in one line. 4) All solutions find a match in `I don't care`

Comment: that ERE should use `\<` and `\>` (start-of-word and end-of-word anchors).  e.g. `awk -F ',' '$4 ~ /\<[Aa]re\>/ {count++;print;} END{print count}'`.   Or maybe just `/ [Aa]re /`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to tackle this problem:

```
sed -Ee '
   y/,/\n/;s/\n/,/3;s//,/3;y/\n,/,\n/
   s/.*\n(.*)\n.*/\1/;s/\<[aA][rR][eE]\>/\n/g
   s/[^\n]*//g;/\n/!d;s///
' file.csv | wc -l
```

Here we are using `GNU sed` and in extended regex mode. The idea is to first isolate the
fourth field and then in a case-insensitive way turn all word(s) "are" found in the pattern space now into newline(s). Then strip away any nonnewline(s) and take away a newline in lieu of `sed` placing of it's own every time it prints something to stdout. then we count the number of lines outputted by `sed` which will give us the sum of all case insensitive patterns of the word "are" in the fourth fields of every line.

```
perl -F, -lane '
   $k += split /(?<=\Ware)(?=\W)/i, $F[3];
   }{print $k-$.;
' file.csv
```

`Perl` we split the fourth field (`$F[3]`) around a case-insensitive word "are" , determined by surrounding "are" with \Ws on both ends. then we update the kount of the number of fields split. Note that the fields shall always be 1 more than the number of "are" words.

At the end of it when all lines have been read and processed, we print the kount minus the number of number of lines in the file.